# Wrapper Class is not covered in the test class

Tags: wrapper-class

I'm having problems with my wrapper class, it is not being covered by my test class.

here is my wrapper class

public class DocuSignEnvelopeWrapper {
    public class Recipients {
        public List signers;
        public List carbonCopies;
    }

```
public class Documents {
    public String name;
    public String fileExtension;
    public String documentId;
    public Blob documentBase64;
}

public class Signers {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String recipientId;
    public String routingOrder;
}

public class CarbonCopies {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String recipientId;
    public String routingOrder;
    public String requiredIdLookup;
}

public String status;
public String emailSubject;
public String emailBlurb;
public List<Documents> documents;
public Recipients recipients;
```

}

and here is my test class I'm just trying to cover at least 1% first but it's still not working
@isTest
public class TestDocuSignWrapper {

```
static testmEthod void myTestUnit1(){
    DocuSignEnvelopeWrapper docuSignWrapper = new DocusignEnvelopeWrapper();
    docuSignWrapper.status = 'sent';    
    docuSignWrapper.emailSubject = 'test';
    docuSignWrapper.emailBlurb = 'test';
}
```

}

it still 0% though... why is this happening? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper class contains no executable lines of code and cannot be covered.

Only executable lines of code are eligible to be counted for code coverage. Variable declarations that don't contain a property declaration or assignment are not executable.

Comment: thanks David Reed! I was able to deploy it :D